# How do I interpret this question: Do I multiply, divide, subtract first?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Which of the following expresses $6p+2py-4p$ in its simplest form?
>
> (A) $2p+2py$
>
> (B) $4py$
>
> (C) $4p^3y$
>
> (D) $10p+2py$

Im not really sure how to go about it...

Comment: That appears to be an addition symbol, $+$, not a division symbol $\div$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Group like terms and simplify.

Answer (score 0):

Notice, $$6p+2py-4p$$$$=(6p-4p)+2py$$$$=2p+2py$$Hence, the option (A) is correct